# How to include the number of a certain figure in the typeout command?

Tags: cross-referencing

It quite often happens to me when working on a living document I mix up the order 
of the figures, e.g., the first figure that I discuss actually is figure number 3.
I don't feel like browsing through a lengthy pdf file each time to check the order of the figures, therefore
I'd like to implement something like the following in the LaTeX source file when I discuss a figure:

```
..in Figure~\ref{figure:someplot} it is shown that..
\typeout{reference to figure [number of figure {figure:someplot}]}
```

so that I can use `grep` on the logfile to check that the figures are referred to in the proper order.

In short, my question is:
How to include the number of a certain figure in the typeout command?

I naively tried something like `\the\ref{figure:someplot}`, which didn't work of course...

Answer (score 4):

It is easiest to use the [`refcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to access the number associated with a reference. Here is a minimal example showing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\printfig}[1]{%
  \typeout{reference to figure \getrefnumber{#1}}% Print information to .log file
}
\begin{figure}
  \centering test 1
  \caption{This is a test figure} \label{first-fig}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering test 2
  \caption{This is another test figure} \label{second-fig}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{first-fig} \printfig{first-fig} and~\ref{second-fig} \printfig{second-fig}.
\end{document}​
```

This outputs the following in your log file:

```
...
reference to figure 1
reference to figure 2
...
```

Of course, this requires the use of `\printfig` whenever it is used. However, this can also be included in the use of the traditional `\ref` command, if needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier `\typeout{reference to figure \getrefnumber{#1}}`? Setting a counter is not required.

Comment: @egreg: That is so true! I was stuck on counters when I wrote the solution. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I programmed a little macro for you, but in the meantime Werner posted a good package based solution which might be better. Anyway, here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\theref[1]{%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\theref@\csname r@#1\endcsname\@@nil
}
\def\theref@#1#2\@@nil{#1}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}%
    \caption{Test}\label{A}
\end{figure}

\typeout{figure \theref{A}}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}%
    \caption{Test}\label{B}
\end{figure}

\typeout{figure \theref{B}}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}%
    \caption{Test}\label{C}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\typeout{figure \theref{C}}

\end{document}
```